# CASE STATEMENT IN SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select CASE WHEN loc ='J' THEN 'Y'
            WHEN loc NOT IN ('J') THEN 'N'
            ELSE 0 END AS loc FROM [prd].[dbo].[GRP]  
            EXCEPT
Select location FROM [prd1].[dbo].[GRPO] WHERE VALUE IN('Y','N');
```

Error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Y' to data type int.

both the columns in both the tables are of same data type `(varchar)` only.

Comment: It's `ELSE 0` that gives your trouble. Change to `ELSE '0'` to fix error.

Comment: This is because your else is an int so it will do an implicit conversion of everything to int because all values have to be the same datatype. Why not simply remove the else? You can't possibly get to that code anyway.

Comment: @SeanLange, You reach the `ELSE` if `loc IS NULL`

Comment: @HoneyBadger yeah...clearly I need another cup of coffee to wake up my brain. It is Friday morning afterall. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Case` statement returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression. Since `0 (INT)` has higher precedence than `Y (Varchar)`, `Y` is implicitly converted to `INT` so you are getting conversion error.

Change `0`(`INT`) to `'0'`(`String`) in `ELSE` statement

```
Select CASE WHEN loc = 'J' THEN 'Y'
            WHEN loc <> 'J' THEN 'N' -- loc NOT IN ('J')
ELSE '0' END
```

Comment: You can't even get to the else from the OPs logic. There are no values where you either = 'J' or don't = 'J'. :)

Comment: @SeanLange -What if it is `NULL`

Comment: SQL Server doesn't care if the `ELSE` is executed or not, it assumes the whole expression is an `int` and for that reason it fails.